# Add/Update/delete in App.config for self-create section

Tags: c#, configuration

I have this code in my project

```
public class SchedulersConfiguration : IConfigurationSectionHandler
{
    public object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)
    {
     // Implementation here to parse xml to object
    }
}
```

and below is the example in my app.config

```
<configSections>
  <section name="schedulers" type="MyClass.SchedulersConfiguration, MyDll" />
</configSections>

  <schedulers>
    <Scheduler name="test1" maxFailureAlert="4" timerType="TypeA" cronExpression="0/10 * * * * ?">
      <property name="customerName" value="CUSTOMER_A" />
    </Scheduler>
    <Scheduler name="test2" maxFailureAlert="3" timerType="TypeB" cronExpression="0/15 * * * * ?" />
    <Scheduler name="test3" maxFailureAlert="3" timerType="TypeC" cronExpression="0/20 * * * * ?" />
  </schedulers>
```

What should I do in order to modify/add/delete the **scheduler** inside **schedulers** section?

I have searched for some time, however, I still couldn't get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ConfigurationCollectionAttribute. It  instructs the .NET Framework to create an instance of a configuration element collection. It also allows to add, remove and clear elements using AddItemName, RemoveItemName and ClearItemsName properties respectively.

You can check more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)